# Where can I set the JRE/JDK which is used to run Netbeans besides the command line?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans6.5

First of all, I know about the command line parameter, but I don't want to use it because I want to learn, not just get it done, so...

**Where can I set the JRE/JDK which is used to run Netbeans?**

A little background:

1. I installed JDK 1.6_10 (The system is Windows Vista Business 64)
2. I installed Netbeans 6.5
3. After a few weeks I uninstalled Netbeans 6.5 (some problems which I hope to solve by a reinstall)
4. I also uninstalled JDK 1.6_10 and installed 1.6_11 instead.
5. I reinstalled Netbeans 6.5
6. Now I cannot start Netbeans because it insists of using the old JDK. (Trying to use the default version doesn't work either. JAVA_HOME is set to 1.6_11)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try setting netbeans_jdkhome in {NetBeans directory}/etc/netbeans.conf.

> # Default location of JDK, can be overridden by using --jdkhome :
>       netbeans_jdkhome="..." # (omitted path, as I have Java in a non-standard location)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the voted answer, here's what I did on my Mac and it worked...

```
(download JDK from Oracle)
$ vi /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
[...]
#netbeans_jdkhome="/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/bin/jre"
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home/"
```

Comment: Thanks for the relevant update to this aging question