# Netbeans 8.2 doesn't start

Tags: netbeans-8

I just installed Netbeans 8.2 with the JDK package. When I open the exe file nothing happens. Looking at the task manager I notice the netbeans service starting then stopping. I tried typing in the --trace command in the command prompt but don't see anything useful for me to fix.

Comment: NetBeans won't start if it can't find the JDK. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10146819/in-netbeans-how-do-i-change-the-default-jdk

Comment: I tried running Netbeans through the command prompt and see this error: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openide/filesystems/FileUtil".  I looked for a solution and seems like the org.openide.filesystems.jar file is missing. I got one from online and put it here "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\lib" and got a different error. I tried reinstalling Netbeans over 10 times so this time I'm trying to fix the issue manually. I wonder if the jar file should go there or if i should go under "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\platform\core".

Comment: Try explicitly specifying the path to the JDK when you start NetBeans form the command line. See http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqJdkHome

Comment: Getting same error, "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openide/filesystems/FileUtil". Seem like I have to add the jar file manually?

Comment: I am using jdk1.8.0_101

Comment: Take a look in NetBeans log file .../var/log/messages.log  (which resides under the directory where you installed NetBeans). Anything relevant there? Also, what O/S are you running?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem because two JDK versions were installed on my pc, so changing the Netbeans needed JDK to lower version solved my problem. here are my passed steps:

**Step One**
In your Netbeans home directory (for example, C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1), open up the netbeans.conf in the etc directory (C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\etc\netbeans.conf).

**Step Two**
There is a property called netbeans_jdkhome. Change the value to match the JDK you want Netbeans to use (for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161).

**Step Three**
Save your changes (user must be Administrator)

**Step Four**
Restart Netbeans

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem. i solved it by reinstalling JDK. but at first i had two applications that were using JDK (intellij and netbeans) when i uninstalled the  intellij the netbeans started to show the problem of starting in task manager and failing on loading the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Some policies in the Network where now I am working changed, so I started NetBeans as Administrator and the problem was solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did solved it by following Mohsen Sabbaghi.In my case i used the jdk1.8.0_301 for the NetBeans 8.2.

For the latest Apache NetBeans 11 the JDK_20 was not working.