# How Can we change Java Platform version for iReport

Tags: java, ireport

In my Widows Machine i have two *Java* version Installed (1.5 and 1.6).

I've installed *iReport 4.0.7*, but it is by default taking *Java* version 1.5 and when I am running it, it is throwing exception.

> A java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError exception has occurred.

Can anyone tell me how can I tell *iReport* to run on *Java 1.6* rather than 1.5.

I've already deleted *Path* and other entry for *Java 1.5* from environment variables.

[image]

Comment: you run jasper in a container or standalone? please check your JAVA_HOME var. make sure it is pointing to the right java version.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34;  and i installed iReport-4.7.0-windows-installer and in installation time i got same exception A java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError exception has occurred.and When i am typing java -version in command prompt i am getting right version

Comment: @subodh Are you talking about using *iReport* or about writing Java application with *JR API*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as I said in comment. if you run your application in a container (say tomcat/jboss/...) with jasper api, you have to check your container conf, to make sure java_home is pointing to right java version.

If your question is about ireport. you could check your `{YourireportPath}/etc/ireport.conf` there you could find one line:

```
# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

uncomment it and make it right. it may solve your problem. Sorry no idea about those advanced features like windows installer.

Comment: @subodh See more details in [Where can I set the JRE/JDK which is used to run Netbeans besides the command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504087/where-can-i-set-the-jre-jdk-which-is-used-to-run-netbeans-besides-the-command-li) post.

Answer (score 1):

17253: iReport 3.7.1, which is bundled with the JasperServer
  installer, needs special handling in order to run with Vista or
  Windows 7. On these OS platforms, iReport  must run with the
  most current versions of Java 1.6 or the current version
  of the Java 1.7 beta. On these OS platforms, iReport will 
  require JDKs greater or equal to: 1.6.0_18-b03 or 1.7.0-b74.
  Additionally, you will need to modify the iReport loader script
  to point to this higher Java version. Edit the following file
  f0`ile: \ireport\bin\iReportLoader.bat

Change this line: SET JAVADIR=%CD%\java
  To this line: SET JAVADIR=\java
  For example: SET JAVADIR=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.`

Answer (score 0):

This is for Ireport-2.0.1

after update updating your Environment variables

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_22

Path=C:\Java\jdk1.5.0_22;
```

(added at the beginning)

Close and Restart iReport by launching the `iReport.bat` file (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Jaspersoft\iReport-2.0.1`)