# Why doesn't netbeans 7.3 see that I've installed Java 1.7.0_21?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've recently installed netbeans 7.3 on my Mac (Lion 10.7.5, up-to-date).
At the command line, I would get:

```
[129]$java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)
```

Today I went to the netbeans plugin window and found 18 updates to install.  When I attempted to do this, I received a message that some of them require > Java 1.7, and I only have 1.6 (as indicated above). So I dutifully ran out to java.com and downloaded Java 1.7 Update 21 successfully.

When I run a Java version checker in various browsers I see a report that Java 1.7.0_21 is the installed version.  In addition, the Mac's Java Control Panel also indicates that 1.7.0_21-b12 is the current version.

However, upon restarting netbeans, it still has the same complaint that Java 1.6 is in use.  I've rebooted the machine and get the same result.  And, the result of 'java -version' at the command line also still shows the same result as above (1.6.0_45).

And, finally, even if I try something like:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_21 --exec java -version
```

I get:

```
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7.0_21"
```

I'm baffled. Does anybody have any advice on this?

Thanks.
Doug

Answer (score 1):

netbeans will be using it's own version of the the JDK try this

[where-can-i-set-the-jre-jdk-which-is-used-to-run-netbeans-besides-the-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504087/where-can-i-set-the-jre-jdk-which-is-used-to-run-netbeans-besides-the-command-li)

Comment: It appears that the thread you indicated is for somebody running on a Windows system.  I found the netbeans.conf file and that the netbeans_jdkhome is a Windows environment variable. I could be wrong, but don't think it applies.

Comment: Having upgraded to Java 1.7 after installing netbeans, I don't have to uninstall netbeans and reinstall it, do I?

Comment: You should not need to reinstall does this site help http://wiki.netbeans.org/JDKVersionAndMacOS

Comment: So, I called AppleCare and was told, "1.7.0_21 is still a high security risk, and Apple disables it.  It can be enabled, but only via the command line via 3rd party instructions.  We won't tell you how, but you can find it by searching around."  Anyway, I suspected that I didn't have a complete installation. So, after getting rid of my current installation of netbeans 7.3, I headed out to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and downloaded both the jdk and the jre+netbeans7.3.  Upgrades now work (except for aproxy/server error on deadlock.netbeans.org).