# Netbeans 14 won't open on mac

Tags: java, netbeans

I just purchased a new computer (mac) on mac os Monterrey.
Neither my old netbeans 11.3 transferred from my old computer or the
newest version netbeans 14, I just installed, seems to work. I
reinstalled java and JDK 17  and restarted and still the same issues.
Netbeans 14 won't open at all; just starts opening and quits
after a few seconds. Netbeans 11 is stuck on initializing any project
forever. Netbeans 14 opened briefly until I allowed it to load some
modules on netbeans 11 on to it. After restarting it no longer even
opens!
This is so frustrating! How can I access all of my projects? I am just not an expert enough to figure this out and no one else seems to have problems with netbeans 14.

Comment: [1] Problems associated with starting NetBeans are written to the NetBeans log file. That log is named **messages.log**, and it is a simple text file. It will reside in a directory named **var** under your _user_ directory. In my case, on Windows 10, its path is _C:\Users\johndoe\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\10.0\var\log_, though obviously it will be different for you. Update your question (only) with any messages appended to the log when you attempt to start NetBeans, being sure to specify the version of Java being used....

Comment: [2] You can explicitly specify the version of Java you want NetBeans to use in the file **netBeans.conf**. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54770359/2985643) for details on how to do that. I'm not a Mac user, but my understanding is that Apple sometimes bundles Java with the O/S, so there may be a conflict between the Apple installed Java, and the version you want to use. Explicitly specifying the JDK path of choice in  **netBeans.conf** will resolve that potential issue. [Here's an (old) example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40869130/2985643) of editing **netbeans.conf** on a Mac.

Comment: I cannot find said messages. log. I have a folder named var but no file called messages. log and nothing pops up under finder either

Comment: I thought from reading around here that it was probably an issue with netbeans not finding java which is why I redownloaded it and I tried to specify it’s location via similar examples. It doesn’t do anything. Maybe because I am new to bash I am doing something wrong.  My version of JDK is jdk-18.02.jdk so I just change it to that version. I saw that these files from the path actually exist on my computer so it should be working.

Comment: This what I tried based on the post you suggested (I tried some other variations as well also based on some other posts):   `$ vi /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 14.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/etc/netbeans.conf
[...]
#netbeans_jdkhome="/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 14.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/bin/jre"
netbeans_jdkhome="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk18.0.2.jdk /Contents/Home/`

Comment: I also tried completely uninstalling and installing netbeans and clearing the cache. No effect. I don't know if any others have this much issue with netbeans. I am thinking it is just too glitchy and might need to try out another IDE.

Comment: worked using omniremover https://www.minicreo.com/mac-uninstaller/uninstall-netbeans-mac.html and reinstalling. Not sure why the first install didn't work well. I did exactly the same thing. These programs are as finicky as my cells.